# My emoji program is showing box with a question mark in C++

Tags: c++, windows, dev-c++

[Error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dchAl.jpg)

I am testing a program to print emoji in C++. My coding environment is Dev C++. But when execute it, it shows a question mark instead of the desired emoji.

Any helpful suggestion to fix my problem would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    system("cls");

    int sml = 1, i, limit;
    char ch = sml;

    cout << "How many smiley face you want to print ? ";
    cin >> limit;

    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        cout << ch << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but i have seen some of these type of program which displays those.

Comment: Your program is correct. The problem is in the console you are using

Comment: Could you please tell me what to do in this current situation?

Comment: am I missing something? `ch` is `1` which is the ascii code for SOH. Why would that print a smiley face?

Comment: @AhanafulAlam ASCII code `1` is SOH (start of header). ASCII doesn't have smiley faces or emojis

Comment: @AhanafulAlam -- The smiley face for ASCII 1 is for the [IBMPC code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).  You need to set the console to that code page.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this working for a console app on Windows 11 with the new Terminal and Visual Studio using UTF8. See https://utf8everywhere.org.

You want to make sure the language and the console are set for UTF8:

```
    auto UTF8 = std::locale("en_US.UTF-8");
    std::locale::global(UTF8);
    std::cout.imbue(UTF8);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_us.utf8");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

I use std::u8string and entered emojis with Win+.

```
    static std::u8string sDead(u8"");
    static std::u8string sLive(u8"");
    static std::u8string sBorn(u8"");
    static std::u8string sOld(u8"");
    static std::u8string sDying(u8"");
    static std::u8string sUnknown(u8"⁉️");
```

And you need to make sure your files are saved as UTF8 in Visual Studio. Click File, Save As... click the down arrow next to save, and click Save with Encoding...

You also need to make sure your Console and Font support emojis.

Full code is here https://github.com/mgradwohl/TerminalLife

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't have any problem, But I can't see the output on vscode. You can also use Unicode and print this: ☺

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
system("cls");
int i, limit;
cout<<"How many smiley face you want to print ? "; 
cin>>limit;
for(i=0; i<limit; i++)
{
// Print ☺ in UTF-8
    cout << "\342\230\272" << "\t";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've used your code but it is remaining the same. showing the same question mark or other characters.

Comment: @AhanafulAlam It works for me on vscode, so It's your console problem. Your console can't show the desired output.

Comment: Will only work on a platform using a utf-8 console (e.g Linux or Mac) not Windows

Comment: @MehdiMostafavi i have used this code in visual studio but it is remaining the same

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my console code page is in 437. but showing the same thing

Comment: @AlanBirtles I use it on windows

Answer (score 0):

The program you've written is correct. It is the console which is at fault. It is unable to print the corresponding character for the `ASCII` value you've passed. I suggest you change the console (On tips for how to do that, you will have to search on Google).

Take a look at my console output:

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me which console you are using?

Comment: @AhanafulAlam he's using a simple Command Prompt of Windows.